# How should I print fractions in a dataframe in Rmarkdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I'm using RMarkdown to write a statistics exam, and I would like to print a discrete probability distribution in a table.  I'm using the MASS library's fractions function because I want to print the probabilities as fractions.  I'm using knitr's kable function to format the table. Here is a MWE of my code:

````
  ---
  output: pdf_document
  ---

  ```{r demo}
  library(knitr)
  library(MASS)
  n <- 5
  x <- 1:n
  p <- fractions(rep(1/n, n))
  df <- data.frame(x = x, p = p)
  kable(df)
  ```
````

I expect the values in the p column to be printed as fractions, but they print as decimals.  How may I achieve my desired result?

Comment: If you look at the return value's class, you can see that `dput(fractions(0.2))` is class `c("fractions", "numeric")`. This means that any function that does not understand what `"fractions"` means will revert to the `"numeric"` method (assuming S3-like operations here). It does not appear that `knitr` recognized `"fractions"` ([searched](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=fractions)), and it does not appear that `kable` uses S3 methods when anything is found with `is.numeric` (incl `"fractions"`). I think @ravic_'s string suggestion is your best bet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way would be to create a string column before posting the output to `kable()`.

```
df <- data.frame(x = x, p = p)
df$fr <- as.character(df$p)
kable(df)
```